# Временной парадокс

Tags: морфология, глаголы

### Вчера иду и понимаю, насколько красива весна.

Как в подобных предложениях определять время глаголов? Вроде бы обстоятельство указывает на то, что действие уже произошло, а форма глагола, наоборот, показывает продолжительность, и это, пожалуй, вводит в некоторое заблуждение по поводу правильности морфологического разбора, в котором, между прочим, есть подобный пункт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Случай, о котором вы пишете, действительно интересен. Это яркий пример так называемых *позиционно обусловленных* языковых явлений.

Обстоятельство *вчера* указывает, что действие относится к прошлому, хотя формы глагола — времени настоящего (ср. *Я понимаю, что ты прав, но не могу согласиться.*). В связи с этим принято говорить о том, что *иду* и *понимаю* — формы **[настоящего исторического времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)**.